# Bash pipe execution order

Tags: linux, bash, operating-system, pipe

If I open an nc in listening on Terminal1

```
nc -l 35555
```

And perform a connection in this way on Terminal2

```
mkfifo /tmp/f
cat /tmp/f | nc 127.0.0.1 35555 > /tmp/f
```

Now I have few questions

On Terminal2 you can see something in waiting. What is that?

- Is it the cat process or the nc process?
- In which order are they executed?

If I write a string on Terminal1, that string just come back.

- Why `cat /tmp/f | nc 127.0.0.1 35555 > /tmp/f` doesn't create a cycle?

The received string comes out from nc and goes in /tmp/f. Because of the cat that string begins input of nc, sent back to Terminal1 and again in /tmp/f etc. etc.

- Why isn't the cat of a fifo a blocking operations? Technically it not end, so why the nc is executed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - Is it the cat process or the nc process?

It's both. `cat` is waiting for something to be written to the FIFO. `nc` is waiting for something to be written to its `stdin` or to receive something over the network socket.

> - In which order are they executed?

All commands in a pipeline are run concurrently.

> - Why `cat /tmp/f | nc 127.0.0.1 35555 > /tmp/f` doesn't create a cycle?

The first terminal is not sending back what it received from the network, it just prints it to the terminal. When you type something on terminal 1 it gets written to the network once. `nc` on terminal 2 writes it to `/tmp/f`. Then it reads it and sends it to the network. `nc` on terminal 1 reads it and prints it. That's the end.

> -Why isn't the cat of a fifo a blocking operations? Technically it not end, so why the nc is executed?

Commands in a pipeline don't wait for the previous one to exit. That would make it impossible to write code like

```
tail -f filename | grep word
```

since `tail -f` never exits (until you kill it with <kbd>Ctl-c</kbd>, but that also kills `grep`). All the processes run, which allows the later programs to process partial output of the earlier programs.

So `nc` doesn't wait for `cat` to exit. It runs at the same time, and probably uses `select()` or `epoll()` to listen for input from both `stdin` and the network socket at the same time (it might also use separate threads for each). So while `cat` is blocking on the FIFO, it can read the network data from terminal 1, and then write it to the FIFO.

Comment: Thanks. A really complete answer